# getting all values of datagridview in loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

i am trying to enter record in database from datagridview filled by textfields so i am using loop to get all records one by one and save it but now problem is that i am unable to get datagridview row[num]  and it giving me error "index must be not null or negative value".

```
 BSL.invoiceDetail idBSL = new BSL.invoiceDetail();
        //MessageBox.Show("proID from datagridview = " + (dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value).ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            idBSL.invoiceId = 1;
            idBSL.proId = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            idBSL.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            idBSL.unitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            idBSL.netProfit = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);


        }
```

Comment: try `i < dataGridView1.RowCount` instead of `i <= dataGridView1.RowCount`

Comment: even that code is outside loop and that also dont work

Comment: @YacoubMassad you were right problem was in last iteration where there was no row left. but i am amaze why it was not working before loop

Answer (score 0):

Two minor corrections in your code.

- `DataGridView` is `0` based index, so loop exit condition should be
  `i < dataGridView1.RowCount`
- Loop not generating the object collection for each row, it is
  updating same instance again and again (`idBSL`)

You have to make both mentioned corrections to make code work.

Alternatively, you can also consider/use below `Linq` approach.

```
var invoiceCollection = dataGridView1.AsEnumerable().Select((row, index) => new {
     invoiceId = index+1,
     proId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value),
     quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value),
     unitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value),
     netProfit = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value)
}).ToList()
```

Comment: thanks @Hari Prasad ,  your first point is correct now its working  but i dont agree about same name of object  perhaps it will create problem in processing but with coding point of view its working .

Comment: I suspect, second point also is valid.  Anyways you are in better to comment this as you see bigger picture :-), does `Linq` solution work for you?